Seeking Assistance with Washing Machine Banging Noise
I'm seeking help identifying possible cause of a recent loud washer noise.   My front load washer (model WF448AAP purchased back in 2010) generally runs fine (maybe slight vibration, but nothing like the video linked below) with light items like socks, shirt, pants.   However, when I throw blankets, pillows, or towels, it creates a loud banging noise when in spin cycle.  I realize an uneven load might lead to more vibration, but the banging doesn't sound right.  My washer is located on the second floor, and I can hear it across the house on the bottom floor.
I've tried simple checks to ensure no funny objects sticking on the inside rubber gaskets. The machine is confirmed mostly level.  The inside tube spins 360 fine w/o any noticable friction or noise.  I'm curious if someone more familiar with the internals and sounds of a washer might be able to suggest possible cause?
Reference Video/Images:
Short 12 second video clip of the banging (~7 seconds into video):
https://1drv.ms/v/s!AjvQtLCRDV7Alu1h2ZuRgidJb32qOw?e=S6pmsc
How I confirmed machine is leveled (I also did same on other sides):

Washer open, the drum looks normal, nothing grossly misaligned, nothing stuck behind those gray rubber seals:

